# Is .document(uid) the same with .whereEqual("uid", uid)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is this operation:

```
db.collection("users").document(uid)
```

The same with:

```
db.collection("users").whereEqual("uid", uid)
```

If a specific uid does not exist, are we still charged with a read operation? Is this available in both cases? Note, that the document is not created yet, there is nothing that can be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
db.collection("users").document(uid)
```

Does not cost any document reads.  No document has been read yet.  The only thing it does is build a DocumentReference object that can be used to `get()` the document (or add a listener).  The `get()` costs a document read.

This code:

```
db.collection("users").whereEqual("uid", uid)
```

Also does not cost a document read until you call `get()` (or add a listener).  But if you do call `get()`, then it will always cost **at least** one document read, even if no document is present.  This is covered in the [documentation for pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge):

> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the first case, when we call get, why it costs one document read even if there is no document to read?

Comment: That's the cost of accessing the massively scalable index used to rapidly find the document no matter how large the collection gets.